# Difference between 'get at' and 'get on at'

Tags: differences, british-english, phrasal-verbs

E.g.

> 'My boss is always getting on at me even if I haven't done anything wrong.'
>
> 'Her parents keep getting at her for skipping classes.'

I'm wondering whether these phrasal verbs have exactly the same meaning or they imply something slightly different.

Comment: Macmillan has both these informal usages.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *to get **on** at someone* is an AmE form. It doesn't sound good to me as a BrE speaker. We normally use one of...

> 1: *He's always getting at her*
>    2: *He's always going on at her*

Semantically they're often effectively interchangeable (though #2 is somewhat more informal). But sometimes *going on* (which more specifically implies *complaining*) isn't quite the same thing as *getting at* *(attacking)*. For example, you can *go on [at someone] about the cost of living* - which doesn't imply you blame the person you're talking to for the thing you're complaining about.

Comment: We normally say *getting on to* , don't we? 'His wife wouldn't stop getting on to him about losing weight.'

Comment: @WS2: If I used ***get on*** at all (which isn't likely), I'd probably go for ***to*** rather than ***at***. In your example both meanings *(complain, attack)* can co-exist. In mine, only *complain* is credible (unless you're a Labour MP attacking Osborne). It's all subtle stuff and often context-sensitive, though I must admit by default I'd interpret *"He's always getting **to** her"* very differently (she's often discomfited by him, but feasibly it's not even deliberate; *attack* is an entirely context-driven nuance).

Comment: There may be some Norfolk here, but does the expression not represent a state of both complaint and attack; perhaps because there is no obvious verb that incorporates both ideas? *The doctor got on to the receptionist for losing the patient's records*. That suggests to me both that the Dr complained, and that in doing so he was 'telling her/him off' (attack). I think if I was *going on at* someone I would be 'having a go at them personally'. *It's no good going on at me about Hilda's drink problem*.  But 'going on about', (e.g) the state of the nation, would not indicate 'at me'.

Comment: In Norfolk they say 'good gracious on to me woman (how can we possibly afford that)'. But that's another story!

Comment: @WS2: When I see *The doctor got on to the receptionist*, I'm expecting ***about*** next because I tend to assume it means *contacted, spoke to, consulted* - in pursuit of information, not to deliver a reprimand. But I think there's considerable variability, much of which isn't strictly "regional dialect". But what do I know? I don't think I've heard *"Good[ness] gracious!"* out in the wild since my grandmother died over ten years ago. It's all *"WTF!"* round my way now.

Comment: Yes, that is another sense altogether *he got on to the suppliers about the delivery*. I suppose it originated as a shortened form of *he got on the phone to the suppliers*. In fact I think, used in that way, that the telephone is almost certainly implied, if not mentioned. I recall the first escalator (moving stairway) being installed in Norwich circa 1957, (at Curls department store, now Debenhams) and someone on the bus, hearing about this saying something to the effect of: *Good gracious on to me, whatever next?*